# Checking if a string is a double or not

Tags: php

I am trying to check in php if a string is a double or not.

Here is my code:

```
   if(floatval($num)){
         $this->print_half_star();
    }
```

$num is a string..The problem is that even when there is an int it gives true. Is there a way to check if it is a float and not an int!?

Comment: Do you want to execute print_half_star() for strings like "4.0"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
// Try to convert the string to a float
$floatVal = floatval($num);
// If the parsing succeeded and the value is not equivalent to an int
if($floatVal && intval($floatVal) != $floatVal)
{
    // $num is a float
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a better one..Samuel

Comment: floatval("24.0") // 24 , So your intval($floatVal) != $floatVal will be false

Comment: seems not to work for strings like "75.00" : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49bad34c2e9b4c417c0711af275014e10d135952

Comment: It wasn't part of question but is a part of problem - this method shows `1.1aaa` is proper float value so in fact, it doesn't check if a string is a double or not.

Answer (score 12):

This will omit integer values represented as strings:

```
if(is_numeric($num) && strpos($num, ".") !== false)
{
    $this->print_half_star();
}
```

Comment: nice method..havent thought about it

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
function isfloat($num) {
    return is_float($num) || is_numeric($num) && ((float) $num != (int) $num);
}

var_dump(isfloat(10));     // bool(false)
var_dump(isfloat(10.5));   // bool(true)
var_dump(isfloat("10"));   // bool(false)
var_dump(isfloat("10.5")); // bool(true)
```

Comment: `isfloat("1e10")` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

You could just check if the value is numeric, and then check for a decimal point, so...

```
if(is_numeric($val) && stripos($val,'.') !== false)
{
    //definitely a float
}
```

It doesn't handle scientific notation very well though, so you may have to handle that manually by looking for `e`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the magic of regular expression

```
<?php
$p = '/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/';
$v = '89.00';
var_dump(preg_match($p, $v));
$v = '.01';
var_dump(preg_match($p, $v));
$v = '0.01';
var_dump(preg_match($p, $v));
$v = '89';
var_dump(preg_match($p, $v));
```

Comment: That regex won't match special number formats containing scientific notation http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: $p='/^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/'; This one allows negative numbers, and integers as double numbers.

Answer (score 0):

if "double string format " like this "XXXXXX.XXXXXX"

try check

```
function check_double_string($str){
 $pairs = explode('.',$str);
 if ( is_array($pairs) && count($pairs)==2) {
   return ( is_numeric($pairs[0]) && is_numeric($pairs[1])? true : false; 
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you have got too much code there.. the first return could simply return true

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all cases of a float we've got to add any zero's back on to the end that may be chopped off by `floatval()` or by typecasting `(float)$num`

```
$num='17.000010';
$num_float = (float)$num; //$num_float is now 17.00001  
//add the zero's back to $num_float
while (strlen ($num) > strlen ($num_float))  $num_float = $num_float . '0';   //$spot_float in now a string again


if($num_float != $num) then $num was no double :;
```

note `!==` was not used just in case `$num_float` was never converted back to a string by adding zeroes.  such would be the case for values that didn't end in 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up creating, for modern PHP:

```php
/**
 * Determines if a variable appears to be a float or not.
 *
 * @param string|int|double $number
 * @return bool True if it appears to be an integer value. "75.0000" returns false.
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException if $number is not a valid number.
 */
function isFloatLike($number): bool
{
    // Bail if it isn't even a number.
    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("'$number' is not a valid number.");
    }

    // Try to convert the variable to a float.
    $floatVal = floatval($number);

    // If the parsing succeeded and the value is not equivalent to an int, 
    return ($floatVal && intval($floatVal) != $floatVal);
}
```