# How to write multiple conditions with functions in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, decimal

I have one function called conversionData() which takes the input from the request and converts based on the type of input .

```
Public static function conversationData (Request $request){
   $value=$request->type;
   if(is_float($value)){
     //return some code
   }
   if(is_string($value)){
     // Return code
   }
   else{
// If it's integer
     return $value;
  }
}
```

if i give in url as **{url}&type=33.34** it should exceute **is_float** condition but it executes ***is_string*** condition.how to execute correctly please help me

Comment: it should be ``if {} else if {} else {}``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for float then integer then string, cheking $value for float using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11849814/10573560):

```
$floatVal = floatval($value);
// If the parsing succeeded and the value is not equivalent to an int
if($floatVal && intval($floatVal) != $floatVal)
{
    // $num is a float
    //return some code
}
```

it's not a float, then continue cheking:

```
     if(is_integer($value)){
         //return some code
       }
if(is_string($value)){
     // Return code
   }
   else{

     return $value;
  }
```

Comment: I need to compare between float and integer also

Comment: I have update my code to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gettype($value)` function and then, usign a switch case you can accordingly apply the logic

```
switch(gettype($value)) {
   case 'integer':
      // write integer code here
      break;
   case 'string':
      // write string code here
      break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

For more information on gettype(); You can refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: ,I have three conditions check float , string and integer value.can I use float instead of integer and integer logic moved to default ...?

Comment: If you have checked the link; it has a 'double' output returned by gettype($value) when you pass a float value to it.